# Are step by step instructions about cross compiling to a linux distro on topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering if a question (I'm thinking of answering my own question) on how to cross compile to a specific Linux distro on topic?

From the help center

> Please note that requests for learning materials (tutorials, how-tos etc.) are off topic.

It is not *really* a request (I will be answering it), but it is a tutorial/step by step instructions. I'm thinking the title will be (to make clearer what my question will be about):

> How can I cross compile to the Raspberry Pi from Arch?

or some similar wording.

I'm under the impression that it is off-topic, is this true? Or can I post it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(In case anyone isn't familiar with how meta works: this is just my opinion, the community will indicate its agreement or disagreement by voting on it)

I don't think you have to worry about the "learning materials" close reason. That's more about overly broad questions, and the idea that an answer is actually supposed to answer the question, not just link to an answer elsewhere.

You pretty much address those concerns by posting a good answer at the same time. That's the first caveat, it needs to be a good answer.

The second concern is that we're focused on users and administrators of Unix-like systems, not developers. Compiling software is a concern of all three groups, but your question and answer should focus on the two that are the site's focus. If you want to focus on development, you'd need to check if it'd be accepted by Stack Overflow or the Raspberry Pi site.